# How to reset the instance name on a SQL Server 2012 re-install?

Tags: sql-server-2012, overwrite, failed-installation

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 on Windows 7 64bit. In the first time, my laptop crashed  during "Installation Progress",  so I have to cancel the installation from Windows Task Manager by ending process.

Now I want to do installation again and replace everything that has already been there. However, since I set the instance name as MSSQLSERVER2012 during the first time, it requires me to set a new one. How could I just overwrite the existed one? Or I have to set a new one and delete the old one after installation? Thx!

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx

Comment: Thx! yes I checked that page. Seems I could not replace the old one during the installation wizard. Instead, I have to delete it after a successful installation, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't overwrite instance names, you will have to uninstall the old one and re-install with the new instance name.